# Multiple pages on a same machine (Linode)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, linode

Im planning to get a Linode plan and i need to run 3 web pages 2 on Ruby on Rails and a simple html is it possible?
i need to have a different URL for each RoR app and for the simple html page also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, I do the exact same thing, plus a couple Sinatra apps.

I recommend reading up on [nginx](http://nginx.org) and [unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) (app server) - they're pretty easy to hook up and managing multiple unicorn instances is as easy as changing the local app server's port in the unicorn config.

Comment: nginx and unicorn are definitely the "way to go", but for a novice, it might be better to just use apache2 and passenger because it "does everything for you"